# Less suggestive terms for "vector addition" and "scalar multiplication"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, terminology

#### Question

Are there less suggestive terms for the two operations commonly referred to as *vector addition* and *scalar multiplication*?

#### Background

In linear algebra, we use the terms *vector addition* and *scalar multiplication* to denote the two operations of a module or a vector space. This terminology was certainly adopted based on the *additive notation* of Abelian groups and the *action by multiplication* of rings or fields. As long as we talk about abstract structures, there is (as far as I can tell) no problem with this.

In the majority of concrete structures that we deal with, the terms do actually correspond to ordinary addition and ordinary multilication. Nonetheless, in many cases there is a conflict between the abstract terms and the concrete operations. As a simple example, just consider the [positive real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332747/proof-that-mathbbr-is-a-vector-space), $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, viewed as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space. Here, vector addition and scalar multiplication correspond to ordinary multiplication and exponentiation by a scalar, respectively.

Comment: Even in less common rings, we still refer to the two operations for the ring as addition and multiplication.  In my opinion, nothing is lost by continuing to use these names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem in tropical geometry as well (in this context, $+$ means "min" and $\times$ means "plus.") I don't know of any less suggestive terms, but my preferred solution is to put square brackets around things as "disambiguators." For example, I might write:

> **Definition.** Let $\mathbb{T}$ denote the "tropical semiring": its underlying set is $$\{[r] : r \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{[\infty]\}$$
>
> Addition is given by taking a minimum:
>
> $$[a]+[b] = [\mathrm{min}\{a,b\}]$$
>
> Multiplication is given by addition:
>
> $$[a][b] = [a+b]$$
>
> It follows that $0_\mathbb{T} = [\infty]$ and $1_{\mathbb{T}} = [0]$.

This basically removes all the ambiguities, at the cost of having to write a lot of square brackets.

Comment: It's also quite uncommon to denote a maximum with $\min$ ☺. I guess you wanted to write "minimum" here.