# complexification of the vector space $\Bbb R^+$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, vector-spaces

Consider $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^+$ as isomorphic vector spaces, with isomorphism $f(x)=\exp x.$

> Is the complexification of $\Bbb R$ isomorphic to the complexification of $\Bbb R^+?$ What is the complexification of $\Bbb R^+?$

I understand that when going from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^+$ under $f$ we have $a+b:=ab$ and $kb:=b^k.$ Here is a relevant link: [vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332747/proof-that-mathbbr-is-a-vector-space).

Comment: did you see the link? the $\exp$ is linear when viewing $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb R^+$ as different vector spaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, isomorphic vector spaces have isomorphic complexifications.

If you're asking how to "implement $\mathbf{R}^{+} \otimes \mathbf{C}$" without unwrapping the isomorphism with the usual vector space structure on $\mathbf{R}$, I don't see a way to do this offhand. At first glance it's tempting to think of the complexification as $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$ with complex multiplication as "addition", and exponentiation as "scalar multiplication". The fatal problem is, the complex exponential mapping is not injective (unlike the real exponential mapping), so to make sense of the operations you end up "taking logarithms" (really, passing to the universal cover), i.e., to the usual vector space structure on $\mathbf{C}$.

Comment: Do you have an idea how to implement this?

Comment: Following up...Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The complexification _is_ $(\mathbf{C},+,\cdot)$ up to isomorphism. One might try to find a vector space structure on the open right half-plane, but because the obvious way map to $\mathbf{C}$ is $u + iv \mapsto (\log u) + iv$, the vector space structure on $(\mathbf{C},+,\cdot)$ is unlikely to look "natural" when transferred to the half-plane, in the sense of "I suspect it can't be done to your satisfaction". But that's more a hunch than a theorem.

Comment: what about $u+iv \mapsto \log(u)+i\log(v)$

Comment: We have to see how the vector space _operations_ are expressed in whatever scheme is proposed. Here, addition of complex numbers corresponds to $$[\log(u)+i\log(v)]\oplus [\log(u')+i\log(v')] = \log(u+u')+i\log(v+v'),$$and complex scalar multiplication corresponds to$$(a+bi)\odot[\log(u)+i\log(v)]=\log(au-bv)+i\log(av+bu).$$(For each, convert the operands to complex numbers by exponentiating componentwise, perform the usual vector space operation, and map back to the open quadrant.)