# Can $\Bbb R^+$ form a field?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Consider $\Bbb R$ as a vector space. We have a vector space isomorphism $\exp:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^+$ where we define new operations $a+b:=ab$ and $kb:=b^k.$

Now a natural inquiry at this point might be:

> Does $\Bbb R^+$ also form a field?

For $\Bbb R^+$ to form a field we need to define addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. Addition has already been defined above as $a+b:=ab.$

Comment: $\exp$ is never a vector space isomorphism.

Comment: @WhatsUp https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332747/proof-that-mathbbr-is-a-vector-space

Comment: Why the negative votes?  Does creativity = $e^{\# \text{negative votes}}$ or something in general on MSE?

Comment: @geocalc33 It's a good question.  And I don't think either of the below answers do it any justice.  You may want to be more explicit about what $\Bbb{R}^+$ is and also use the $e^x$ notation so people don't confuse the notations.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "form a field"? Usually we say a set forms a field _under this and that operation_. Which operations do you want to know $\mathbb R^+$ forms a field under? That is, which addition and which multiplication?

Comment: Hah this question made me go back to a blog post I wrote some years ago about putting group and ring structures on arbitrary sets. It was probably the most clever thing I've done. It wouldn't help here since it was based on the axiom of choice, so it is not constructive in the way you want.

Comment: @CameronWilliams do share a link !

Comment: Here you go! http://mathematics-abound.blogspot.com/2015/06/putting-group-and-ring-structures-on.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then the question asks whether it is possible to define a "multiplication" map $m: \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+\rightarrow \Bbb R^+$ such that, together with the "addition" map $a: \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+ \rightarrow \Bbb R^+$ sending $(a, b)$ to $a\cdot b$, makes $\Bbb R^+$ a field.

This is of course possible, in view that $\exp$ is an isomorphism of abelian groups from $(\Bbb R, +)$ to $(\Bbb R^+, \cdot)$.

We simply define the field structure on $\Bbb R^+$ by pushing out the field structure on $\Bbb R$ via the $\exp$ map.

More explicitly, we define $m: \Bbb R^+ \times \Bbb R^+ \rightarrow \Bbb R^+$ by sending $(a, b)$ to $\exp(\ln(a)\cdot \ln(b))$, which is equal to both $a^{\ln (b)}$ and $b^{\ln (a)}$.

Comment: You've missed the question.  The question is can we form a "higher field" given that $+$ and scalar mult sort of use up "all there is".  Or is there a commutative multiplication definable that distributes over $+$ and isn't the same thing as scalar mult.  It's a good question IMHO.

Comment: $\ln$ is undefined for $0$ (the identity for addition), so your solution, as is, is inapplicable to $\Bbb R_+$, as closure is a requirement for all operators of a field. You probably meant $\Bbb R_+^*$. In that case, addition in $(\Bbb R, +)$ is indeed mapped to an abelian group (with identity 1). The structure $(\Bbb R, m)$ is however not an abelian group.  $e$ is the identity, there are inverses, it is commutative, but there is no associativity of $m$ (the binary operator does not generalize well to $n$-ary operations). It looks like distributivity might also be an issue, but I didn't check.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne $\Bbb{R}^+ = \{ r \in \Bbb{R} : r \gt 0 \}$ I thought.

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder That is wrong. By convention $\Bbb R_+ = \{r \in \Bbb R | r \geq 0 \}$, and $\Bbb R_+^* = \{r \in \Bbb R | r > 0 \}$. In abstract algebra, writing $E^*$ means the (multiplicatively) invertible elements of $E$. For a field, that means the set $\Bbb F - \{0\}$

Comment: @TristanDuquesne I think that in the OP's context, $\mathbb R^+$ likely means the set of all positive real numbers. This can be seen from the OP's mentioning of the exponential map. If this is the case, associativity and the distributive property are satisfied...

Comment: @user1551 yes that's what I meant. ( $\Bbb R^+$ means the set of all positive real numbers in this context)

Comment: ...That is, when $a\otimes b=\exp(\ln(a)\ln(b))$ and $a\oplus b=ab$,
\begin{aligned}
a\otimes(b\otimes c)
&=\exp\left(\ln(a)\ln(b\otimes c)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\ln(a)\ln(b)\ln(c)\,\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\ln(a\otimes b)\ln(c)\right)\\
&=(a\otimes b)\otimes c,\\
a\otimes(b\oplus c)
&=a\otimes(bc)\\
&=\exp\left(\ln(a)\ln(bc)\right)\\
&=\exp\left(\ln(a)\ln(b)\right)\exp\left(\ln(a)\ln(c)\right)\\
&=(a\otimes b)(a\otimes c)\\
&=(a\otimes b)\oplus(a\otimes c).
\end{aligned}

Comment: @TristanDuquesne I don't understand your complain. Firstly, $\Bbb R^+$ denotes the set of all positive real numbers. Now for $a, b\in \Bbb R^+$, I define $a \oplus b = ab$ and $a \otimes b = \exp(\ln(a)\ln(b))$. I claim that $(\Bbb R^+, \oplus, \otimes)$ is a commutative ring, with zero element $1$ and unit element $e$, and is in fact a field. Don't you agree with me? In case no, could you point out which axiom of ring or field is not satisfied?

Comment: @user1551 The author quite possibly meant the set of all (strictly) positive real numbers, but given that such structures often fail being parts of a category for minute details, it's good to be technically thorough.
Also, small correction for my message above, I wrote $(\Bbb R, m)$, but of course meant $(\Bbb R_+^*, m)$
Finally, I stand corrected by you, WhatsUp's answer is indeed correct, and is a way to turn $\Bbb R_+^*$ into a field. They have earned my upvote.

Comment: @TristanDuquesne Oh, I'm glad that you agree with me now (:

Answer (score 2):

The power operator only has a right identity, $1$, and no left identity, so no. It is also not associative nor commutative.

**Edit, to elaborate, since a comment asked for it:**

If an identity element exists in an algebraic structure, it is unique (posit $u$ and $u'$ are different identities for the same magma, you can show they are equal).

$\forall a \in \Bbb R, a^1 = a$ but $1^a = 1$. So the (unique) identity for the power operator is $1$, but it only works on one side (the right side). It is thus not "sufficiently" an identity for it to be the identity of a monoid (*a fortiori* group, ring, field) operator.

Additionally, it is not commutative. In general, $a^b \neq b^a$, such as $2^3 = 8 \neq 9 = 3^2$.

Finally, it is not associative. By convention, we choose to read `a^b^c` as `a^(b^c)`, ie $a^{b^c}$ or $a^{(b^c)}$ (operating from right to left), since `(a^b)^c` corresponds to $(a^b)^c$, or `a^(b*c)`.

Comment: Could you explain some more?

Comment: @StudySmarterNotHarder Edited just for you.

Comment: So just to understand, $\Bbb R^+$ as I've defined it is a vector space but can't be made into a field?

Comment: I think the more interesting question is to find addition and multiplication operations that make $(0, +\infty)$ a field.

Comment: @jskattt797 You should look at WhatsUp's answer and the comments then. :)